# Do I need to test my website on iPad 2 as well as iPad 1?

Tags: ipad, testing

I currently have an iPad 1 which I use to test websites ive made. Do I need to also get an iPad 2, or if it works on 1 will it always work on 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will also work in the iPad 2. The same software runs on iPad1 and iPad2. It's just faster hardware.

Comment: Is the screen size the same? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is. Same resolution, same screen size.